# Porting a datasource to Glassfish

Tags: java, datasource, glassfish-3

How do I define the following in Glassfish 3? In a sensible, ideally JavaEE6 compliant, file - not by manually clicking through a web UI.

```
<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>FizioDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fizio</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>fizio</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from my *domain.xml* file for a MySQL datasource. Maybe it is helpful for postgreSQL as well:

```
<jdbc-connection-pool connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
           datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" 
           res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
           wrap-jdbc-objects="false" 
           name="mysql_ladb_adminPool">
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://helios:3306/ladb" />
      <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="Password" value="pass" />
      <property name="portNumber" value="3306" />
      <property name="databaseName" value="ladb" />
      <property name="User" value="user" />
      <property name="serverName" value="localhost" />
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="mysql_ladb_adminPool" jndi-name="jdbc/ladbadmin" />
```

Put it inside the `<resources>` section of domain.xml.